# xcodebuild failing to fetch a swift package

Tags: continuous-integration, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I've a swift Xcode (14.3.1) project that has some dependencies to swift packages, one of those is coming from a developer public github repo, while compiling the project with Xcode all works fine once a new Source Control Account (`Xcode->Settings->Accounts`) is added with the proper git PAT key.

While trying to compile the same identical project with `xcodebuild` it does not work:

```
xcodebuild -project SwiftPackage.xcodeproj -scheme SwiftPackage
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project SwiftPackage.xcodeproj -scheme SwiftPackage

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Resolve Package Graph

Fetching from https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git (cached)

Fetching from https://github.com/apple/swift-system.git (cached)

Fetching from https://github.com/USERAME/PACKAGE(cached)
skipping cache due to an error: Couldn’t fetch updates from remote repositories:
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Fetching from https://github.com/USERAME/PACKAGE (cached)

skipping cache due to an error: Couldn’t fetch updates from remote repositories:
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

  Failed to clone repository https://github.com//USERAME/PACKAGE:
    Cloning into bare repository '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftPackage-crqxawsrsuqwaabsatcmymebbugz/SourcePackages/repositories/PACKAGE-21375f48'...
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

`SwiftyJSON` and `swift-system` are fetched correctly, but `PACKAGE` no..

I've tried different solutions found on Stackoverflow, like configuring the `.netrc` file, modifying the `*.xcodeproj` such that the package URL contains the PAT (PAT@github...), changing the `*.resolved` file to again contain the PAT, this works somehow but it looks like a hack not a fix.

Also, changing the clone method in Xcode (`Xcode->Settings->Accounts`) to `HTTPS` or `SSH` does not change anything.

What I need is a clean solution like adding `-scmProvider xcode` that sadly does not work, in other words: Is there an option for `xcodebuild` specifically such that it works as Xcode does and fetch properly the packages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

1. It looks like your xcodebuild command is using your system git instead of its own embedded git (which ignores the local/global git configuration settings). Since it works and uses the accounts credentials you need when building through Xcode's UI, you could try switching it back to use Xcode's own embedded git:
   `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM NO`
2. Then delete all derived data (with Xcode shut down):
   `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. Then try resolving the package dependencies alone first (with Xcode still shut down):
   `xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -project ./YourProjectName/YourProjectName.xcodeproj`
4. Then you can try compiling normally with xcodebuild.

Alternatively, if you have git settings that you rely on in your local environment, you could try updating Xcode's embedded git config and settings with whatever you rely on in your global git config.